# Kubernetes: Options to restore an ETCD cluster

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

With regard to saving/restoring a snapshot, I usually do the following (on my local node, not master):

ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints="https://127.0.0.1:2379" --cacert=/opt/local/ca.crt --cert=/opt/local/etcd-client.crt --key=/opt/local/etcd-client.key snapshot save /etc/data/etcd-snapshot.db

In the docs, there are two options for restoring.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#built-in-snapshot

The first is this:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --data-dir <data-dir-location> snapshot restore snapshotdb
```

...which is fine if etcd is on the your master so you could copy the snapshot restore dir to master and update the etcd.yaml with the new path so it starts to use the new backup.

The second option is this:

ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints="https://127.0.0.1:2379" --cacert=/opt/local/ca.crt --cert=/opt/local/etcd-client.crt --key=/opt/local/etcd-client.key snapshot restore /etc/data/etcd-snapshot.db

I assumed that if we use --endpoints and URL and include the certs, it would update the ETCD DB directly but this doesn't seem to be the case as the command runs OK but ETCD isn't restored with previous data.

Would really appreciate any guideance, can't seem to find an answer online as there's so much on the topic and so many different options.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same dilemma: what appears, in [the k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#restoring-an-etcd-cluster), to indicate that restore may be performed via the network. At least for the `etcdctl snapshot restore` style commands (pre `etcd 3.5`, where they seem to have [switched](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/recovery/#restoring-a-cluster) to `etcdutl` for restoring), the `--endpoint` parameter seems to have zero effect.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --debug 
  --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2378 
  --cert=servertypo.crt 
  --key=servertypo.key 
  --cacert=catypo.crt 
  snapshot restore /tmp/a.db
```

The `snapshot restore` option creates a new directory, in the current directory, named `default.etcd`, where a restored etcd datadir is created (`member/` a.s.o.), completely ignoring the `--endpoints` option - as you can see, the port is wrong.

The `--datadir` parameter does change this location (thus, `default.etd` is the default value for `--datadir`).
Same goes for the `--cacert`, `--cert` and `--key` parameters, which seem to be completely ignored - if you notice above, I included "*typos*" for all three - they do not exist.

So, from what I gather, there's **no** "*online restore/network restore*" option (i.e. via the network - or at least I wasn't able to find it.